# multiply a number from a list and a number from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I am currently trying to multiply a number from a list with a number from a text file however I get the error= `Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NonType'` ,

Does anyone have a better method for doing this ?

```
text_file =open("read_it.txt", "r")
pricetxt=print(text_file.readlines()[2])
price1 = pricetxt*(items2[1])
print(price1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print()` returns None and you are preserving it in `pricetxt()`. Also you need to convert the result which is a string to `int` (if it's a correct data). Also note that you better to use a `with` statement for opening the file, because it will close the file automatically at the end of the block.

```
with open("read_it.txt") as text_file:
    try:
        price = int(text_file.readlines()[2])
    except ValueError:
        # do something else
    else:
        new_price = price * items2[1]
```

Note that also `items2[1]` needs to be integer. If it's not you have to convert it to integer, which you can do it in `try` block after `pricetxt`.

Comment: I suppose once it's converted to an `int` the variable name should be `priceval` or `price` rather than `pricetxt`.

Comment: thanks that looks very neat. Is a number in a list accounted as an integer or a string ?

Comment: guys I tried to convert items2 into an integer through list(map(int , items2)) , but it gives an output of the number 23 , 5 times = 2323232323 , it does not multiply them.

Comment: guys i used items2 = [int(i) for i in items2] instead and it works.